# nginx configuration working on local servers but not on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nginx

I am sending a request to my Java server via nginx as a load balancer. 
Below mentioned is the configuration of nginx server present at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http{
upstream demoApp{
            server  192.168.0.223:8000;
            server  192.168.0.222:8888;
            }
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://demoApp;
            proxy_connect_timeout       300;
            proxy_send_timeout          300;
            proxy_read_timeout          300;
            send_timeout                300;
               }
       }
   }
```

In local environment, this configuration works fine, but when I do the same changes in config file of nginx hosted on AWS, the access.log shows 200 as response status code but at my server end(java code), I receive no data.
Any input on where the problem is, would be appreciated.
Thanks....

Edit-:

My nginx is working fine only when all the setups are only at one server.
If nginx and the java code are running on different server on a local enviroment, my nginx stops working as expected that is it does not forward the request.

Comment: What happens when you ping demoApp from the EC2 server? it should point at your server end.

Comment: It seems the server is configured on some VM in your local environment and is not configured in your EC2 instance.

Comment: 13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 11999ms . This is the output I get when i try to ping. I have also edited my question a bit.Please look at it as well

Comment: @Yaron-: If I am not using EC2 instance and all the setup is on local environment, and ping is working fine on local environment,,    still nginx is not forwarding the request but request coming to nginx is logged in access.log file.

Comment: Are you using Nginx on your local environment setup?

Comment: yes. initially I was using ec2 instance but now i am trying to run it on local instance first. Nginx is not working in local environment with above configuration.